# Game of Thrones Wikipedia Python scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

Hay i'm making a second school project and is a Python Scraper with the help of BeautifulSoup . Okay my assignment says the following: that i should assemble an app that scrapes the date from Wikipedia and gives a number of total view from all the seasons of GoT extra is if the app could make the following: displays the totals of all seasons before the grand total and could also give the the total views episode by episode and the the totals and in the grand end the grand total of all.

Like that:
S01E1:2.22 Milions
S02E2:2.20 Milions
.
.
.
Total vievs of season 1: xy

Grand total : 398,7 milions

Somehow i managed just the grand total.

If somebody has done something similar please help :)
Thanks a lot :

```
import re
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones'
wiki_html = urllib.urlopen(wiki_url).read()
wiki_content = BeautifulSoup(wiki_html)

seasons_table = wiki_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})
seasons = seasons_table.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('\/wiki\/Game_of_Thrones_\(season_?[0-9]+\)')})

views = 0

for season in seasons:
    season_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + season['href']
    season_html = urllib.urlopen(season_url).read()
    season_content = BeautifulSoup(season_html)

    episodes_table = season_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'})

    if episodes_table:
        episode_rows = episodes_table.findAll('tr', attrs={'class': 'vevent'})

        if episode_rows:
            for episode_row in episode_rows:
                episode_views = episode_row.findAll('td')[-1]

                views += float(re.sub(r'\[?[0-9]+\]', '', episode_views.text))  # here we search for numbers in the text with a help of a regex (regular expression)

print 'The total number of views is ' + str(views) + ' millions'
```

Comment: Add a line between `episode_views = episode_row.findAll('td')[-1]` and              `views += float(re.sub(r'\[?[0-9]+\]', '', episode_views.text))`  Won't tell you what as its a school project

Comment: Is it possible for you to specify the exact location of the data you are after, i meant under which title? Otherwise one has to comb the full page to find that.

Comment: sure i am after Adaptation schedule <th style">Season</th> to select the seasons 1,2,3....and then  in Episode after the value in #mw-content-text > div > table.wikitable.plainrowheaders.wikiepisodetable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(7) does that help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like Ali told you, except you should not sum it, but just output it and sum it in separate variable  in my case:

```
totalViewsPerSeason
```

Working solution:

```
import re
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones'
wiki_html = urllib.urlopen(wiki_url).read()
wiki_content = BeautifulSoup(wiki_html)

seasons_table = wiki_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})
seasons = seasons_table.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('\/wiki\/Game_of_Thrones_\(season_?[0-9]+\)')})

views = 0
grandTotalViews = 0
season_num = 1

for season in seasons:
    season_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + season['href']
    season_html = urllib.urlopen(season_url).read()
    season_content = BeautifulSoup(season_html)

    episodes_table = season_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'})

    if episodes_table:
        episode_rows = episodes_table.findAll('tr', attrs={'class': 'vevent'})

        if episode_rows:
            episode_num = 1
            totalViewsPerSeason = 0
            for episode_row in episode_rows:
                episode_views = episode_row.findAll('td')[-1]

                views = float(re.sub(r'\[?[0-9]+\]', '', episode_views.text))  # here we search for numbers in the text with a help of a regex (regular expression)
                grandTotalViews += views
                totalViewsPerSeason += views
                print 'S' + str(season_num) + "E" + str(episode_num) + " : " + str(views) + " Millions"
                episode_num += 1

    print "Total season " + str(season_num) + " views: " + str(totalViewsPerSeason) + " Millions\n"
    season_num += 1

print 'The total number of views is ' + str(grandTotalViews) + ' millions'
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no work needed in for parsing. All I had to do was work on how to output the results on the screen in the format you want in the question, more like string manipulation.

Code:

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones'
wiki_html = urllib.urlopen(wiki_url).read()
wiki_content = BeautifulSoup(wiki_html, 'html.parser')
seasons_table = wiki_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})
seasons = seasons_table.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('\/wiki\/Game_of_Thrones_\(season_?[0-9]+\)')})

views = 0
total = 0
season_num = 1
for season in seasons:
    season_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + season['href']
    season_html = urllib.urlopen(season_url).read()
    season_content = BeautifulSoup(season_html,'html.parser')
    episodes_table = season_content.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'})
    if episodes_table:
        episode_rows = episodes_table.findAll('tr', attrs={'class': 'vevent'})
        if episode_rows:
            episode_num = 1
            for episode_row in episode_rows:
                episode_views = episode_row.findAll('td')[-1]
                views = float(re.sub(r'\[?[0-9]+\]', '', episode_views.text))  # here we search for numbers in the text with a help of a regex (regular expression)
                total += float(re.sub(r'\[?[0-9]+\]', '', episode_views.text))  # here we search for numbers in the text with a help of a regex (regular expression)
                print 'S' + str(season_num) + "E" + str(episode_num) + " : " + str(views) + " Millions"
                episode_num += 1
    season_num += 1

print 'The total number of views is ' + str(total) + ' millions'
```

Output:

```
S1E1 : 2.22 Millions
S1E2 : 2.2 Millions
S1E3 : 2.44 Millions
S1E4 : 2.45 Millions
S1E5 : 2.58 Millions
S1E6 : 2.44 Millions
S1E7 : 2.4 Millions
S1E8 : 2.72 Millions
S1E9 : 2.66 Millions
S1E10 : 3.04 Millions
S2E1 : 3.86 Millions
S2E2 : 3.76 Millions
S2E3 : 3.77 Millions
S2E4 : 3.65 Millions
S2E5 : 3.9 Millions
S2E6 : 3.88 Millions
S2E7 : 3.69 Millions
S2E8 : 3.86 Millions
S2E9 : 3.38 Millions
S2E10 : 4.2 Millions
S3E1 : 4.37 Millions
S3E2 : 4.27 Millions
S3E3 : 4.72 Millions
S3E4 : 4.87 Millions
S3E5 : 5.35 Millions
S3E6 : 5.5 Millions
S3E7 : 4.84 Millions
S3E8 : 5.13 Millions
S3E9 : 5.22 Millions
S3E10 : 5.39 Millions
S4E1 : 6.64 Millions
S4E2 : 6.31 Millions
S4E3 : 6.59 Millions
S4E4 : 6.95 Millions
S4E5 : 7.16 Millions
S4E6 : 6.4 Millions
S4E7 : 7.2 Millions
S4E8 : 7.17 Millions
S4E9 : 6.95 Millions
S4E10 : 7.09 Millions
S5E1 : 8.0 Millions
S5E2 : 6.81 Millions
S5E3 : 6.71 Millions
S5E4 : 6.82 Millions
S5E5 : 6.56 Millions
S5E6 : 6.24 Millions
S5E7 : 5.4 Millions
S5E8 : 7.01 Millions
S5E9 : 7.14 Millions
S5E10 : 8.11 Millions
S6E1 : 7.94 Millions
S6E2 : 7.29 Millions
S6E3 : 7.28 Millions
S6E4 : 7.82 Millions
S6E5 : 7.89 Millions
S6E6 : 6.71 Millions
S6E7 : 7.8 Millions
S6E8 : 7.6 Millions
S6E9 : 7.66 Millions
S6E10 : 8.89 Millions
S7E1 : 10.11 Millions
S7E2 : 9.27 Millions
S7E3 : 9.25 Millions
S7E4 : 10.17 Millions
S7E5 : 10.72 Millions
S7E6 : 10.24 Millions
S7E7 : 12.07 Millions
The total number of views is 398.73 millions
```

Comment: great code but i has a problem it adds the views from a episode 1 to episode 2 and episode 1,2,3 sum to episode 4, but what it neeeds to do is to give you the views of episode 1 :2.22 milion

Comment: and then continues to do so for all the episodes and then give you a seasons total and in the end the grand total